# Picasso transform with ScaleType

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I'm using Picasso for displaying images and I want to make my ImageView with rounded corners. So I used this library for transformations: https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations. Rounded corners are applying but I can't see them because I am using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. In this way corners are out of view. How do I make the corners rounded with scaleType?

Here is my imageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/articleImg"
        android:src="@mipmap/image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

and here is code in adapter:

```
final int radius = 30;
final int margin = 5;
final Transformation transformation = new RoundedCornersTransformation(radius, margin);
Picasso.get().load(model.getImage_url()).transform(transformation).into( holder.imageView);
```

Here is the result:
[image: Imageview without rounded corners because of ScaleType]

Answer (score -1):

try to set scale attribute programmatically

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Comment: added in adapter after setting picasso, so it didn't help :(

Comment: I don't know how this works, but made it like this: Picasso.get().load(model.getImage_url()).resize(500, 400).centerCrop().transform(transformation).into( holder.imageView);

Comment: U crop image size to 500x400